# is NFC Host-Based Card Emulation possible in dart/flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, nfc, hce

I am making a flutter app that uses NFC to communicate with other android mobiles, I already found projects that implement this, however, they are made in kotlin or java [this](https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid), is there a way to implement this in dart/flutter?

packages such as [nfc_emulator](https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_emulator) do not work for me I have tried their example and nothing happens once I read it from another device. i would really appreciate any help in this

Comment: What AID did you use with the nfc_emulator and what code did you use to the the device?

Comment: @Andrew I used the AID provided in the example in their pub dev page, as for the reader device I used the NFC manager library,(they have an app in the play store that demonstrates the library called "NFC manager " that uses the NFC manager library)

Comment: If you can do it in Java/Kotlin, you can do it in Flutter. Just use the Java/Kotlin code and call it with a platform channel. Also, that package only emulates NFC. You want something like [`nfc_manager`](https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager).